# create plugin Zoom Box in open suite sdk

Tags: boundless-suite

How create plugin zoom box in opengeo-suite sdk? 
I need to zoom by dragging with mouse.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what SDK? Since there is a GXP template, and openlayers 3 templates. Since you mentioned plugin I assumed the gxp template.

Comment: yes, is gxp template

Answer (score 1):

There is box zooming in the existing Zoom plugin if you configure it with `showZoomBoxAction: true` https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gxp/blob/master/src/script/plugins/Zoom.js

Comment: which is the configuration? because that configuration if look...